# Trying to hide Header logo in email based on an attribute Value in Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, email-template

I am trying to hide the email logo if the value of variable platform!=BFY but show the logo if its =BFY while retaining the overall email structure intact. here are the AMPscript and HTML code im trying to write in the header. any advice how to do this, please?

```
%%[
VAR @Platform

IF v(@Platform) == "BFY" THEN

SET 
@Photo = "http://image.s4.exct.net/lib/fe9d15747166047976/m/1/BFY-logo-blue_243x69.png"

ELSE
SET @Photo = null

ENDIF
]%%
```

somewhere in header html>  `img src="%%=v(@Photo)=%%" width="243" height="69" alt="BenefitsForYou">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like below -

```
%%[
SET @Platform = AttributeValue("Platform")
IF @Platform == "BFY" Then
SET @Image = "https://image.s4.exct.net/lib/fe9d15747166047976/m/1/BFY-logo-blue_243x69.png"
]%%

   <img src="%%=v(@Image)=%%" width="243" height="69" alt="BenefitsForYou">

%%[EndIF]%%
```

Comment: Yess, This works perfectly, Palash. Thanks for your help. Thanks@Adam and @Toby for your support as well.

Answer (score 1):

If `Platform` is column in your DE (or a Profile Attribute), then I'd write it like this:

```
%%[
VAR @Platform, @photo

set @Platform = AttributeValue("Platform")

IF @Platform == "BFY" THEN

  SET @photo = "http://image.s4.exct.net/lib/fe9d15747166047976/m/1/BFY-logo-blue_243x69.png"

ELSE

  /* 1x1 gif from http://png-pixel.com/ */
  /* could also be any other transparent PNG or GIF */
  set @photo = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="

ENDIF
]%%
<img src="%%=v(@photo)=%%" width="243" height="69" alt="BenefitsForYou">
```

**EDIT**

To control the dimensions, I'd just add height and width variables:

```
%%[
VAR @Platform, @photo, @height, @width

set @Platform = AttributeValue("Platform")

IF @Platform == "BFY" THEN

  SET @photo = "http://image.s4.exct.net/lib/fe9d15747166047976/m/1/BFY-logo-blue_243x69.png"
  set @height = "69"
  set @width = "243"

ELSE

  /* 1x1 gif from http://png-pixel.com/ */
  /* could also be any other transparent PNG or GIF */
  set @photo = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
  set @height = "1"
  set @width = "1"


ENDIF
]%%
<img src="%%=v(@photo)=%%" width="%%=v(@width)=%%" height="%%=v(@height)=%%" alt="BenefitsForYou">
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Adam. It worked :). Now the a small challenge i have is how to reduce the space where we display logo when no logo is shown. it seems big gap between email pre-header and email body

Comment: IN Gmail test send it's displaying logo placeholder like image and no reduction in space between preheader and body

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting just the photo URL based on the value of the variable, try setting the whole table based on the value of the variable.

Another note, if all you're doing in this table is displaying an image, you might want to get rid of the table altogether and try just an image tag with a simple style:

```
<img src="http://image.s4.exct.net/lib/fe9d15747166047976/m/1/BFY-logo-blue_243x69.png" style="width:243px; height:69px;margin-left:calc(50% - 122px);" alt="BenefitsForYou" />
```

Using tables for positioning is generally considered a no-no in modern HTML standards. This will also simplify your AMPscript.

I'm far from an AMPScript expert but using your AMPscript as a guide, something like this:

```
<!--%%[
VAR @Platform = lookup('extensionName', 'columnName', 'nameOfColumncontainingSubKey', _subscriberKey)
IF @Platform == "BFY" THEN
SET @Photo = "<a title='BenefitsForYou' href='https://www.benefitsforyou.com' target='_blank' conversion='false' alias='BenefitsForYou link'>
                  <img src='http://image.s4.exct.net/lib/fe9d15747166047976/m/1/BFY-logo-blue_243x69.png' style='height:69px;width:243px;margin-left:calc(50% - 122px);margin-right:calc(50% - 121px);' alt='BenefitsForYou'>
              </a>"
ELSE
SET @Photo = null
ENDIF
]%%-->
%%-v(@Photo)=%%
```

[Style Test:](https://putsmail.com/tests/07d74b56-fb4b-4bb4-bf05-7b6d850dcaff)
[image]

Comment: HI Toby, Really appreciate your help but i'm still not able to do it and the reason i use tables is because its email campaign and tables are only and preferred method to code email to prevent rendering issues in all modern email clients.

Comment: What is not working about it?

Comment: I used https://putsmail.com/tests/07d74b56-fb4b-4bb4-bf05-7b6d850dcaff to send a test email with the HTML I provided and don't see any issues with the formatting.

Comment: Formatting seems ok. I tried setting the whole table method but now its not showing the image for everyone even for records where value is BFY. seems issue in AMpScript condition.

Comment: I removed the "v()" function from the IF Statement as the examples I found online don't have this. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Tried. NO luck yet

Comment: I made one more quick edit, the value of platform is not ever actually being set. Make sure you assign a value to it.

Comment: value of Platform is coming from Data Extension which has the valid data against it.

Comment: Use the lookup function to populate platform: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookup/